# Javascript - Not Reversing the show/hide

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/16we0dwu/)

Would like to have the user hit 'yes' and it show the # field and then hit 'no' to hide it. Do I need another function on the 'no' to do this?

```js
var empNumber, radios;

function showReqEmp() {
    if (!radiosChecked()) {
        empNumber.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        empNumber.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

function showReqEmp(id) {
    var a = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!radiosChecked()) 
        a.style.display = 'none';
    else 
        a.style.display = 'block';
}

function radiosChecked() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('returning_employee');
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++)
    if (radios[i].checked) return true;
    return false;
}
showReqEmp('requiredNum');
showReqEmp('requiredNumText');
```

```html
<font color="Red">*</font>Returning Employee:</td>
<input type="radio" name="returning_employee" value="Yes" onclick="showReqEmp('requiredNum'); showReqEmp('requiredNumText')">Yes
<input type="radio" name="returning_employee" value="No" onclick="showReqEmp('requiredNumText'); showReqEmp('requiredNum')" />No
<lable id="requiredNumText" style="display:none"><font color="Red">*</font>Employee Number:</lable>
<lable id="requiredNum" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" id="employee_number" name="employee_number" placeholder="123456789">
```

Ok so now I ran into this issue with the validation.
[Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/16we0dwu/1/)
The show/hide works but i cant get the validation to check if they entered data after hitting 'yes'

```js
var numberExp = /^[0-9\-]+$/;
function validate()
  {
        if(document.newempRequest.returning_employee.checked && !(document.newempRequest.employee_number.value.match(numberExp)))
  {
  alert("Please provide the employee number");
  document.newempRequest.employee_number.focus();
  return false;
  }
        return true;
  }
```

I have tried to alter the input tags to differ the yes/no but that breaks the show/hide

The HTML code is same as above.

Comment: `<font>` is deprecated. Use CSS instead.

Comment: Having functions with the same name doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Those labels are messed up. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Comment: @danielnixon - This website is old and was created before my time and was never suppose to be used in the way it is now. haha If I had the time to dedicate to this I could change a lot of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply modify the `radiosChecked` function to return `true` only if the `Yes` checkbox is checked.

```
function radiosChecked() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('returning_employee')[0];
    return radios.checked;
}
```

The original Code:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('returning_employee');
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++)
if (radios[i].checked) return true;
return false;
```

Would return `true` even if any of the check box in the group is checked. Hence the toggling would not happen.

Comment: Or just: `return radios.checked;` ;)

Comment: @DonBottstein - Changed to reflect your comments. Much better.

Comment: Got any ideas about validating the text field after the 'yes' radio is checked?

Comment: @Benny-Answering your comment as part of this question would make it too broad in the context of the original question. However you could post a new question and post a link to it. You would get precise answers. But you need to write a function that does the validation on the `radios` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it CSS-only, without JS:

```css
#requiredNum {
  display: none; 
}
#returning_employee_yes:checked ~ #requiredNum {
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
*Returning Employee:

<input type="radio" name="returning_employee"
       id="returning_employee_yes" value="Yes" />
<label for="returning_employee_yes">Yes</label>

<input type="radio" name="returning_employee"
       id="returning_employee_no" value="No" />
<label for="returning_employee_no">No</label>

<label id="requiredNum">
  *Employee Number:
  <input type="text" id="employee_number"
         name="employee_number" placeholder="123456789" />
</label>
```

Comment: I would like to use CSS but this is an old website and its not my primary to redesign it. I will keep this for future reference. Thank you.